# NodeJS mongo driver find statement with projection returning full document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have below funtion to filter only `order_id` from `info` collection.
Instead of getting `_id` and `order_id` callback is getting all key, values from database.
Node version: 9.4
Mongo version: 3.4

```
var listCollections=function (columns,db,callback) {
    if (columns.length===0) {
        return callback('No columns specified')
    }
    columns.forEach(function (col) {
        query[col]=true;
    });
    db.collection('info').find({},{order_id:true}).toArray(function (mongoError,result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
};
```

Please correct me here, but as far as documentation of mongo driver goes, my syntax is correct.
How do I get only specified columns from collection?

Comment: Could you post a link to the documentation you are using?

Comment: I am referring to [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#making-queries-with-find)

Comment: The link is for driver v1.4.9. Are you sure you use this version? The earliest version of the driver compatible with mongo 3.4 is 2.2.12: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#node-js-driver-compatibility

Comment: @AlexBlex its 3.0.1. Thanks for pointing out version mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[find](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find) method of the Collection accepts a single parameter in nodejs driver - the query itself.

[projection](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project) is applied to the cursor:

```
db.collection('info')
  .find({})
  .project({order_id:1})
  .toArray(function (mongoError,result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Its working.. I was referring to https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#making-queries-with-find and it clearly states we can use  second param of find as projection itself.
Maybe I am on wrong version of node/mongo

Answer (score 1):

Use "**fields**" option.

```
**db.collection('info').find({},{fields:{_id:0,name:1}}).toArray(function (mongoError,result) {
        console.log(result);
    })**
```